# Can't Figure out this "array index is out of range" Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here are my variables

```
string[,] table = new string[104, 6];
int moveRow = 1;
int moveCol = 1;
int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;
int rowIndex1 = 1;
int rowIndex2 = 0;
int firstTableRow = 1;
int firstTableCol = 1;
int secondTableRow = 1;
int secondTableCol = 0;
int thirdTableRow = 0;
int thirdTableCol = 1;
int fourthTableRow = 0;
int fourthTableCol = 0;
int counterNextRow = 0;
```

Now it's giving me (just for me) a weird `Array index is out of range` here

```
if (moveRow > 1)
{

   firstTableCol += 1;
   secondTableCol += 1;
   thirdTableCol += 1;
   fourthTableCol += 1;
   //r1 = table[2,1] r2 = table[2,0] r3 = table[1,1] r4 = table[1,0]
   string d1 = table[firstTableRow, firstTableCol]; //<------- HERE ITS GIVING ME THE ERROR
   string d2 = table[secondTableRow, secondTableCol];
   string d3 = table[thirdTableRow, thirdTableCol];
   string d4 = table[fourthTableRow, fourthTableCol];

   moveRow += 1;
}
```

Here is my whole code for that

```
for(int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); col++){
     for (int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++)
     {               
            //if not equal length BLUE[0] else RED[1]
            //moverow = 1, movecol = 1 default
            if (table[moveCol, moveRow] == null)
            //1,1
            {
                //must be on table[2,0]
                //scan 
                //3,2
                string col1 = table[rowIndex1, row];
                string col0 = table[rowIndex2, row];

                if (col1 != null)
                {
                    sum1++;
                }
                if (col0 != null)
                {
                    sum2++;
                }
                counterNextRow += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //if not null and on the first process
                if (counterNextRow == 0)
                {
                    //r1 = table[1,1] r2 = table[1,0] r3 = table[0,1] r4 = table[0,0]
                    string d1 = table[firstTableRow, firstTableCol];
                    string d2 = table[secondTableRow, secondTableCol];
                    string d3 = table[thirdTableRow, thirdTableCol];
                    string d4 = table[fourthTableRow, fourthTableCol];


                    if (d1 != null && d2 != null && d3 != null && d4 != null)
                    {
                        img.texture = (Texture)NewTexture[1];
                        p.SetActive(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        img.texture = (Texture)NewTexture[0];
                        p.SetActive(true);
                    }
                    moveRow += 1;
                }
                //hindi unang process
                else
                {
                    if (moveRow > 1)
                    {

                        firstTableCol += 1;
                        secondTableCol += 1;
                        thirdTableCol += 1;
                        fourthTableCol += 1;
                        //r1 = table[2,1] r2 = table[2,0] r3 = table[1,1] r4 = table[1,0]
                        string d1 = table[firstTableRow, firstTableCol];
                        string d2 = table[secondTableRow, secondTableCol];
                        string d3 = table[thirdTableRow, thirdTableCol];
                        string d4 = table[fourthTableRow, fourthTableCol];


                        if (d1 != null && d2 != null && d3 != null && d4 != null)
                        {
                            img.texture = (Texture)NewTexture[1];
                            p.SetActive(true);
                        }
                        else if (d1 != null && d2 != null && d3 == null && d4 == null)
                        {
                            img.texture = (Texture)NewTexture[1];
                            p.SetActive(true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            img.texture = (Texture)NewTexture[0];
                            p.SetActive(true);
                        }
                        moveRow += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        firstTableRow += 1;
                        secondTableRow += 1;
                        thirdTableRow += 1;
                        fourthTableRow += 1;
                        //r1 = table[2,1] r2 = table[2,0] r3 = table[1,1] r4 = table[1,0]
                        string d1 = table[firstTableRow, firstTableCol];
                        string d2 = table[secondTableRow, secondTableCol];
                        string d3 = table[thirdTableRow, thirdTableCol];
                        string d4 = table[fourthTableRow, fourthTableCol];


                        if (d1 != null && d2 != null && d3 != null && d4 != null)
                        {
                            img.texture = (Texture)NewTexture[1];
                            p.SetActive(true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            img.texture = (Texture)NewTexture[0];
                            p.SetActive(true);
                        }
                        moveRow += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //condition that if 1st board column 1 and column 0 has an equal length
        //mark on the 2nd board
        if (sum1 == sum2)
        {
            //red[1]
            img.texture = (Texture)NewTexture[1];
            p.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            //blue[0]
            img.texture = (Texture)NewTexture[0];
            p.SetActive(true);
        }
        //increment everytime the column is finish scanning
        sum1 = 0;
        sum2 = 0;
        rowIndex1++;
        rowIndex2++;
        moveCol++;
        moveRow = 1;
   }
 }
```

I've been stuck here because of that error and i don't why it is giving me an `Array index is out of range` error . I don't have any negative numbers there so supposedly I won't be having that kind of error. Could someone point me out .

Comment: What is the value of `firstTableRow` and `firstTableCol` at that point?

Comment: @Steve I'm very sorry but when i tried to put a break point it is continuous so i can't figure out when it is popping out .

Comment: You could use [Debug.Log](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) to print the values to the Console. The answer will probably be that one or the other (or both) values are greater than the size of your `table` array.

Comment: `rowIndex1` starts at 1 instead of 0 so that may be the issue. I didnt read all your code but that is my gut feeling

Comment: @CodingYoshi it wouldn't throw i guess an error because is it just for my scanning of the whole specific column

Comment: Yes it will if that index does not exist. Imagine you have a house with 2 rooms and you want to scan the 3rd room-there is no 3rd room so exception.

Comment: @Steve I added some `Debug.Logs` on every `tables[table[firstTableRow, firstTableCol];` i have so here are result : `Values of tables Cols : 1010, Values of tables Rows: 1100, Values of tables Cols3: 1010, Values of tablesRows3 :2211, Values of tablesCols2 :2121, Values of tablesRows2 :2211, Values of tablesCols2 :3232, Values of tablesRows2 :2211, Values of tablesCols2 :4343, Values of tablesRows2 :2211, Values of tablesCols3 :4343,Values of tablesRows3 :3322,Values of tablesCols2 :5454,Values of tablesRows2 :3322` then `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: It's definitely because the index you're trying to get it larger than the size of the array. You'll need to investigate why and add some protection to check for size before accessing the array, or break out of the loop.

Comment: @Steve like `.Length()`

Comment: @steve Breaking out is a hack. It means there is a bug in code and you are writing code to protect against it. All of the code, in this scenario, is under full control so why the safeguards.

Comment: That's how you can get the size, but you should try and find out why you're getting the error in the first place.

Comment: @CodingYoshi it depends on what they are trying to achieve. It may be legit to break once the index reaches the size limit. I agree in this case something is going wrong to increase the index beyond the limit.

Comment: Hmmm sorry for this very dumb question . what array should I get the size

Comment: @steve No it is not. The code is right there so why is the algorithm looking for an index that does not exist? The algorithm needs to change and not allow getting into such a situation.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I'm agreeing with out, all I'm saying is that breaking out of a loop once an index reaches a particular size is not *necessarily* a hack. It all depends on context. In this case, yes, the code needs to be fixed.

Comment: @steve I cannot think of such a situation. But lets get back to this question and leave our discussion for a beer ;)

Comment: I guess ` table rows 4 and column 4 is out of range`

Comment: Your code seems overly complex and minimally descriptive (variable names in particular are mostly meaningless).  Which line is the error occurring on, what are the array index values being used and what is the lengths of the arrays?

Comment: @Immersive it is stated on my questino

Comment: I guess I'll just wrap it with a try and catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm i forgot to check the length of my variables to the dimension I am using . So by doing like this for example my variable `rowIndex1` I need to check it like this

```
if(rowIndex1 + 1 < table.GetLength(0)){
    rowIndex++;
}
```

Thanks guys for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Array index rang must be 0 to 103 rather than 1 to 104. It might solve your problem.

```
int moveRow = 0;
int moveCol = 0;
```

Comment: rowIndex1 is also initialized to 1. I do not know the purpose of your code but rowIndex1 is a cause of the problem.

Comment: I guess I'll just wrap it with a try and catch?

Answer (score 0):

Your `moveRow` and `moveCol` is starting from 1 and your for-loop is 0 based. So your `moveCol` is one higher than your for loop indexer.

Comment: I tried doing `moveRow = 0` and `moveCol = 0` but get the same output

Comment: I guess I'll just wrap it with a try and catch?

Answer (score 0):

You table is defined as `[columns, rows]` but you appear to be indexing as `[rows, columns]`